# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am getting the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined?" error, when I try to fetch a particular contact (provided a phone number) from my contacts saved in a file.

```
exports.query = function(number) {
   var json_result = JSON.parse(read_json_file());
   console.log(json_result);
   var result = json_result.result;
   for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      var contact = result[i];
      if (contact.primarycontactnumber === number)    {
         return contact;
      }
   }
   return null;
};
```

I am calling the above code as:

```
  app.get('/contacts/:number', function(request, response) {
   response.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
   response.end(JSON.stringify(contacts.query(request.params.number)));
 });
```

The code of my read_json_file method is:

```
function read_json_file() {
   var file = './data/contacts.json';
   return fs.readFileSync(file);
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `json_result` when you log it to console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that `json_result` does not have property `result`. If it fits into your function logic, you can defensively set `result` variable like this:

```
var result = json_result.result || [];
```

what will assign empty array to `result` variable if `json_result.result` is undefined (or evaluated to false).